# Sonarlint: 'Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise' incorrect

Tags: async-await, sonarlint

I'm getting this sonarlint warning (Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise) on a section of JS code but I can't for the life of me see this issue:

```
const checkKey = async key => {
  const result = await pool2.query(`SELECT * from "tb_keys" where key='${key}'`);
  return result.rowCount > 0;
}
export const cloneProject = async ({key, projectid}) => {
  const validkey = await checkKey(key); // Warning appears here
  ....
}
```

As the checkKey function is async it automatically returns a promise, so I'm confused why sonarlint is complaining about the await?

For clarity, pool2 is a PostreSQL pooled connection.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour - just about all my `await`s are being flagged as redundant by sonarQube. I wonder if it's something in the environment? I'm using VS code 1.59.0 with SonarLint v2.0.0.0 and node v12.22.1 on ubuntu 20.02